How to find N and e knowing that e = p and N = p*q?
I've been stuck in this problem for a while, this is a challenge about Symmetric RSA:
We know that

$N = p*q$
$e = p$
$ct = pt^p  \bmod N$ (1)

We are given $ct$ (which is the flag encrypted) and 4 more $ct$ where we can freely choose 4 numbers (plaintext) then the server will return new CT respectively using $p$ and $N$ (we don't know $p$, $q$ and $N$). How to find $p$ and $N$? I tried to do research on my own and something seem to be helpful are Little Fermat and DLP
Little Fermat:
$a^p \equiv a \bmod p$ ($p$ is prime and $a$ is not divisible by $p$)
DLP:
$g^x \equiv h \bmod p$ Then what is $x$?
Please help me I will be very grateful.

$\text{ct}\equiv\text{pt}^p\bmod n$ is ambiguous. It can be read as $\text{ct}\equiv\text{pt}^p\pmod n$ which means $n$ divides $\text{pt}^p-\text{ct}$ and thus does not uniquely define $\text{ct}$, allowing e.g. $\text{ct}=\text{pt}^p$ or $\text{ct}=\text{pt}^p-42,n$.  Also, why $N$ and $n$? I think it's meant $\text{ct}=\text{pt}^p\bmod N$, where$\bmod$ is an operator meaning remainder of the Euclidean division

Thanks fgrieu for helping me, I edited the question to make it clearer. I do understand the finding q part but we don't have N how can I find its factors?

Revised hint: using a single pair $(m,c)$ with $c=m^p\bmod N$ and $1<m<N-1$, and Fermat's little theorem, we get a multiple of $p$. Using two, we get $p$. From there, uh, thinking about it.

Thanks fgrieu for your help. I found out the answer for this question.
Recover p
First we compute:
$ct1 = 2^p  \bmod N$
$ct2 = 3^p  \bmod N$
$gcd$ ($2$,$N$) and $gcd$ ($3$,$N$) should be $=$ 1
So that we can apply Fermat's little theorem:
$2^p \equiv 2  (\bmod p)$
$3^p \equiv 3  (\bmod p)$
after rearranging, we got:
$ct1 - 2 \equiv 0  (\bmod p)$
$ct2 - 3 \equiv 0  (\bmod p)$
Since they are divisible by p, then we can find p by using gcd:
$p = gcd(ct1 - 2, ct2 - 3)$
Recover N
We sent -1 to server:
$ct3 = (-1)^p (\bmod N)$
Because $p$ is odd so $(-1)^p = -1$
$ct3 \equiv -1 \equiv N - 1 (\bmod N)$
then $N = ct3 + 1$

If the server did not accept the input $-1$, we could in principle also get $N$ (or a typically small multiple thereof) as $\gcd(2^p-\text{ct2},3^p-\text{ct3})$. We can then pull the small factors, if any. Or, rarely, we'd need one or two other queries to get the actual $N$. Problem is the numbers involved are huge, so at least the fist step of the GCD needs to be done specially.
